# Getting facebook group members

Tags: facebook-graph-api, member, group

I am an administrator of a facebook group (community). Using the FB API, I would like to get all group members (Name, Emails)
I've also made a facebook app (still in development).  Having the:

- app_id
- app_secret
- groupId
- accessToken

Would it be possible to get all group members, where I am the group owner ? At the moment I m getting this feedback:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#3) Missing Permission",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 3,
    "fbtrace_id": "AxZZccy0vawUvSxP6DtTyLI
"
  }
}
```

I remember in the past it was possible, but now with the new regulation, I m not sure. Maybe you know more .

Thank you